# LINQ Include a child array of select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I have the following LINQ query which is working great :

```
public IList<Course> GetEmployeeCourses(int id) {
  var employeeCourses = Context.Employees
    .Where(e => e.Id == id)
    .SelectMany(e => e.employeeCourses.Select(ec => ec.Course))
    .ToList();

  return employeeCourses;
}
```

The issue is, I now need to also include a child array (Urls) of the selected Course when returning the Course array.

Something like :

```
public IList<Course> GetEmployeeCourses(int id) {
  var employeeCourses = Context.Employees
    .Where(e => e.Id == id)
    .SelectMany(e => e.employeeCourses.Select(ec => ec.Course))
    .Include(c => c.Urls)
    .ToList();

  return employeeCourses;
}
```

With it returning JSON like this : (The Course model has over 15 properties though)

```
[
  {
     "Name": "Course1",
     "Type": "Maths",
     "Location": "Block C",
     "Urls": [
          {
            "Link": "https://url1forcourse1.com"
          },
          {
            "Link": "https://url2forcourse1.com"
          }
      ]
  }
  {
     "Name": "Course2"
     "Type": "Computer Science",
     "Location": "Block A",
     "Urls": [
          {
            "Link": "https://url1forcourse2.com"
          },
          {
            "Link": "https://url2forcourse2.com"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
     "Name": "Course3"
     "Type": "The Art of Dish Washing",
     "Location": "Block E",
     "Urls": [
          {
            "Link": "https://url1forcourse3.com"
          },
          {
            "Link": "https://url2forcourse3.com"
          }
      ]
  }
]
```

How would I achieve this in the most efficient way? I cant seem to get the child array called 'Urls' at all at the moment, its always null.

Also, i'm using Fluent API with this EmployeeCourse config:

```
ToTable("EmployeeCourses");

HasKey(q => new { q.CourseId, q.Employee.Id})

HasRequired(x => x.Employee)
   .WithMany(x => x.EmployeeCourses)
   .HasForeignKey(x => x.CourseId);

HasRequired(x => x.Course)
   .WithMany(x => x.EmployeeCourses)
   .HasForeignKey(x => x.EmployeeId);
```

Comment: If this `EF6` or `EF Core`? Please be specific and tag accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to use chained `SelectMany` as:

```
public IList<Course> GetEmployeeCourses(int id)
{
  var employeeCourses = Context.Employees
                        .Where(e => e.Id == id)
                        .SelectMany(e => e.employeeCourses
                        .SelectMany(ec => ec.Course))
                        .Include(c => c.Urls)
                        .ToList();



    return employeeCourses;
}
```

Comment: This gets the Urls but i need a list if Courses with nested child Urls in each Course

Comment: @DBoi Have a look. It should work now. It will provide `Name` and `Urls`.

Comment: HI MKR, thanks for helping me out. Although the example above only has the 'Name' and 'Urls' property for the Course, my app has many Course properties including 'Name', 'Type', 'Location' ete etc (Over 15 properties). Is there a way to get all the props in the Course model as well as the Urls child array? As opposed to getting them individually.

Comment: @DBoi I have updated my answer. Have a look. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

From [Eagerly loading multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data):

> Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity
>   also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is
>   achieved by use of the Include method.

You can try like this, therefore it allows you to load all `EmployeeCourses` and related `Courses`

```
public IList<Course> GetEmployeeCourses(int id) {
  var employeeCourses = Context.Employees
    .Where(e => e.Id == id)
    .Include(e => e.employeeCourses.Select(ec => ec.Course))
    .SelectMany(e => e.employeeCourses.Select(ec => ec.Course))
    .ToList();

  return employeeCourses;
}
```

Comment: At what point does this include the Urls? They are a child array of Course.

Comment: As far as I understand `Urls`is property of `Course` class, is that right? If so when you include `Course` you can easily get `Urls`

Comment: How can I easily get Urls?